# fully connected layer in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

[fully connected layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fq3t.png)

I wanted to implement this siamese network in Tensorflow. Each network become a seperate patch, we do a sepearate convolution + relu + maxpooling for each patch then we have a decision layer (fully connected layer) which decides if the classification result is true or false. I don't know how to concatenate the results from the 2 networks in a fully connected layer

I have joined a picture of the network above. 
**Color used in the picture** : cyan = Conv+ReLU, purple = max
pooling, yellow = fully connected layer (ReLU exists between
fully connected layers as well).

My Code

```
x1 = tf.reshape(x1, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x1, weights['W_conv1']) + biases['b_conv1'])
conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1)   

x2 = tf.reshape(x2, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x2, weights['W_conv2']) + biases['b_conv2'])
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2)
```

Comment: If I am correct, you have to connect two conv-net (conv1 and conv2) in one fully connected layer. To do that you can use: ```fc = self.fc_layer(conv1 or conv2, "fc")``` on both and further concatenate both fully connected layers.

Comment: yes that is what I meant but I don't know the syntax to concatenate the 2 fully connected layers

Comment: use tf.concat. (DOC: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat)